# Decompressing multiple files at once

Tags: bash

I have more than 200 `.zip` files in one folder. I don't want to decompress those one by one. I want to extract those using single command or script. How to do that.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you really want to uncompress them in parallel, you could do

```
for i in *zip; do unzip "$i" & done
```

That however, will launch N processes for N .zip files and could be very heavy on your system. For a more controlled approach, launching only 10 parallel processes at a time, try this:

```
find . -name '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} -P 10 unzip {}
```

To control the number of parallel processes launched, change `-P` to whatever you want. If you don't want recurse into subdirectories, do this instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} -P 10 unzip {}
```

Alternatively, you can install [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) as suggested by @OleTange in the comments and run

```
parallel unzip ::: *zip
```

Comment: Running in parallel is a nice idea, but won't disk I/O be the major bottleneck?

Comment: @PaddyLandau not sure, I'd have to check. It will depend on the speed of the decompression algorithm vs the speed of the disk I imagine.

Comment: Use `-exec` or `-execdir` instead of piping to `xargs`. Not only is it simpler to understand, but also it's also less error-prone and uses fewer system resources. `find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} ';'` (You must quote the semi-colon.)

Comment: @PaddyLandau the only reason I'm piping to xargs is to run things in _parallel_ as the OP asked. `-exec \;` (you can escape the semicolon, no need for quotes), will run each command sequentially. `-exec +` is better but it won't work here since that's not how `unzip` works.

Comment: I think that we have understood the OP differently. You read him as wanting it in parallel, whereas I understood him as meaning a single command instead of multiple commands. Well, he has both methods now :)

Comment: For followers, in this case `xargs -0 -I {} -P 10 unzip {}` means "take null delimited input, one line at a time [-I implies -L1] and put it where the `{}` string is"

Answer (score 18):

The [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command is well suited to this type of thing.  After:

```
$ sudo apt-get install parallel
```

Then

```
ls *.zip | parallel unzip
```

This will use as many cores as you have, keeping each core busy with an unzip, until they are all done.

Comment: It's a better idea to use `echo *.zip` instead to prevent a possible ls alias from sneaking in extra info. However, this has the same issue as @Guru's answer, it breaks on file names containing whitespace.

Comment: @nyuszika7h In contrast to `xargs` GNU Parallel does _not_ break on file names containing space/tab/quote. Only if the file names contain newlines you will have to take extra care. For example by using: `parallel unzip ::: *.zip`

Comment: @nyuszika7h - These are good reasons to avoid _both_ aliasing standard commands, _and_ putting spaces in filenames.

Comment: @nyuszika7h using `echo` is as bad as using `ls`. Globbing and a while loop is the safest.

Comment: @WayneConrad It's pretty common to alias `ls` to `ls --color=auto`. Is there another way I'm missing to get that behaviour? As for spaces in file names, sometimes they look better with spaces. I only tend to use them for music and videos (e.g. `01 - Pilot.mkv`). On the other hand, putting **line feeds** in file names makes absolutely no sense, but unfortunately programs have to consider the possibility to be on the safe side. I'd like to punch the person who thought it would be a good idea to allow line feeds in file names in face.

Comment: Since I cannot edit my previous comment anymore, I'd like to add an amendment: *line feeds and similar characters*.

Comment: @nyuszika7h I hadn't thought of that.  In fact, my ls has the --color=auto alias as well.  It seems as though _that_ particular alias is harmless for this purpose.  I guess that if ls is being piped to a non-console device, it leaves out the color codes.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes, that one should be harmless.

Comment: @terdon You're right, but `echo` is still a bit safer than `ls`, IMO.

Comment: @nyuszika7h no, try (in an empty directory) `touch 'aa bb' 'cc dd'; echo * | xargs rm` for example. It will have exactly the same issues as `ls`. Plus, `echo` can have [other problems](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222) (thought those are not that relevant here admittedly).

Comment: @terdon You're not proving anything with that, it doesn't counter the fact that `echo` will work even if you have `ls` aliased to something that would break the `ls` version. I understood the fact that `echo` has the same issue as `ls`. However, you're right about the other part. echo is a nasty compatibility command and should be probably avoided unless you're just printing literal text.

Comment: @nyuszika7h - I think that what terdon is getting is that echo has _different_ problems than ls.  `ls` will break this answer if it has been aliased to, e.g., `ls -l`.  On the other hand, `echo` will break this answer if there are spaces in the filename.

Comment: @WayneConrad No offense intended, but you aren't good at reading either. I **did** say "However, you're right about the other part.", which was about echo's issues. I missed those at the point when I suggested `echo` instead of `ls`. Also, no, `echo` won't break in that case, but rather if the file name starts with something like `-e` or `-n` or perhaps if it contains escape sequences.

Comment: @nyuszika7h I think if you reread what you wrote, you may find that there is some ambiguity in it.  In any case, no offense taken.  I think we've beaten this horse to death.

Comment: Depending on the machine, there's a good chance that `parallel` may make the process slower.  These days unzipping a file tends to be limited by I/O speed, not CPU.  If you unzip one file at a time, you get sequential I/O which is fast, but if you unzip many simultaneously, they take turns accessing the disk, possibly forcing many expensive seeks.

Comment: @NateEldredge While that chance was bigger back in the time when systems had only one magnetic disk, these days with RAIDs with multiple spindles and flash disk that chance is smaller. The best thing to do is of course to measure and see how _your_ system behaves. I recently used a 40 spindle RAID where the optimal parallelism for I/O hungry processes was 10: It did not give a 10x speed up - only a 6x, but fewer than 10 processes gave less than 6x.

Comment: Too bad it has that annoying citation header so isn't a drop in replacement for xargs... :|

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following command :

First change directory in terminal to directory that contains .zip files :

```
cd /path
```

Then execute this command to unzip all .zip files :

```
for z in *.zip; do unzip "$z"; done
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have many `.zip` files in your folder and you want to decompress all of them then open terminal and go to your folder using:

```
cd <path_to_folder>
```

Now use this command to decompress all your `.zip` file:

```
ls *.zip | xargs -n1 unzip
```

Comment: This will fail if any of the file names contain whitespace.

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: It's a better idea to use `echo *.zip` instead to prevent a possible `ls` alias from sneaking in extra info, however that still does not fix the whitespace issue.

Comment: @OleTange In case you didn't notice, I said that it still fails on file names with whitespace in them.

Comment: Never depend on the output from `ls` for scripts, as its output is not well-defined between versions. Instead look at the answer from @terdon as it solves all the problems of this solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use find with `-exec` like so,

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} \;
```

This **will** work if the file has a space in the name.

Answer (score 3):

A non terminal method.

Just select the zip files, right click on one and choose `extract here`. You can select all or just a number of zip files at a time.

Answer (score 2):

`unzip \*.zip` or `unzip '*.zip'`

The obvious `unzip *.zip` doesn't work, because the shell expands it to `unzip foo.zip bar.zip ...` and `unzip` interprets the first filename as the zip file, and the following filenames as files to extract from that zip file.

However, `unzip` is a bit unusual among Unix commands in that it does its own glob expansions.  If the `*` is not expanded by the shell, unzip will do it, and intepret all the resulting filenames as zip files to be processed.  So in this special case, one can get away without a `for` loop or `xargs` or the like.